# Disable Rebase button after rebase in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

In Gerrit it's possible to rebase a commit in the change window. Is it possible to disable or hide this button after the patch has been successfully rebased?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but if the pathset is already rebased when you click in the "Rebase" button then in the new popup window the "Rebase" button will be disabled:

[image]